# Delete forward from cursor to the end of HTML tag in VIM?

Tags: html, vim

We can delete all contents in HTML tag with "**dit**".

But my question is, in the example, I want to keep the first line and delete the rest, without using a command like "*7dd*".

Is there a better way than use "***7dd***" in this case? Thank you.

```
<section className="booklist">
  <Book /> ==> I want to keep this line, and delete the rest
  <Book />
  <Book />
  <Book />
  <Book />
  <Book />
  <Book />
  <Book />
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly move to the beginning or end of text objects, I think, but one way to achieve what you want in your example and keep the advantage of using the "tag" text object would be

`Vitojd`

As in, line-wise visually select the contents of the tag, jump to the first line of the selection, de-select it (by moving down), delete.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant:

```
vit<Esc>d''
```

- `vit<Esc>` visually selects the whole inner tag but what we really want is the side effect of moving the cursor to the end of the area so we leave visual mode.
- `d''` cuts from here to the line we were on just before the last vertical motion.

Here is another one:

```
V/sec/-<CR>d
```

- `V/sec/-<CR>` enters visual-line mode and extend it to the next occurrence of `sec` minus one line.
- `d` deletes the visually selected lines.

Comment: Thank you for the second solution. However when I try the first `vit<Esc>d''` solution, it also deletes `</section>`. I'm using Vim plugin for VSCode. I try again with `vit<Esc>kd''` and it works.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between `V/sec/-<CR>d` vs `V/sec/-<Enter>d`? Both works in this example.

Comment: 1. That "Vim plugin for VSCode" is not Vim. It is an incomplete *emulator* so there is no reason whatsoever to expect anything to work in that thing as it does in Vim or the other way around. 2. The proposed commands work *for your sample*. If you add more levels of indenting, then the solution may be different. Everything is contextual, in Vim. 3. `<CR>` and `<Enter>` are synonyms. `<Return>` is another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `d/<string>` to remove everything up to the first occurrence of `<string>`.

To do this in your example: place a cursor at the third line on the first column and type: `d/<\/sec` and press `<CR>` (`Enter`) to remove lines.

---

The only drawback of this method is that it changes the last-search register (`"/`).

Comment: Note that the cursor should be positioned on the first column.

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution of "Vitojd" answered below also dealt with the search register proglem. Also I didn't know that we have to use \/ for / , which can sometimes be quite awkward to press.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be `d/<string>/-`

In this example: `d/sec/-`

However the cursor has to be at the **beginning** of **first** `<Book />`